# bootstrap login form overlap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I want to create to different login form. How do i put my login container besides each other? I tried adjust the column grid but it didn't work. I tried add col-sm-12 and add col-sm-6 to each login-container.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="login-container">
        <div id="output"></div>
            <div class="avatar"></div>
                <div class="form-box">
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin" action="login2.php" method="post">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="login-container">
        <div id="output"></div>
            <div class="avatar"></div>
                <div class="form-box">
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin" action="login2.php" method="post">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="login-container">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div class="avatar"></div>
        <div class="form-box">
          <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin" action="login2.php" method="post">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="login-container">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div class="avatar"></div>
        <div class="form-box">
          <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin" action="login2.php" method="post">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your HTML structure. Currently you're first `col-sm-6` is closed inside a container and row before you reach your second `col-sm-6`. Both columns should be inside the `container` and `row`. See [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

See example Snippet.

```css
/**FOR DEMO ONLY**/

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.login-container {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px 15px 5px;
}
/**FOR DEMO ONLY**/

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h3>Stacks @ Under 768px</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="login-container">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div class="avatar"></div>

        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin" action="login2.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="login-container">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div class="avatar"></div>

        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin" action="login2.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Never Stacks</h3>
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="login-container">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div class="avatar"></div>

        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin" action="login2.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="login-container">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div class="avatar"></div>

        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin" action="login2.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="login-container">
            <div id="output"></div>
            <div class="avatar"></div>
            <div class="form-box">
                <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin" action="login2.php" method="post">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="login-container">
            <div id="output"></div>
            <div class="avatar"></div>
            <div class="form-box">
                <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin" action="login2.php" method="post">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the `.row` div too early. Take one of the `</div>`'s out of the middle and place it at the end.

I'd also update your column divs to `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">` just to maintain some consistent padding for small screens.